# How to create a portrait iAd banner view for iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, iad, adbannerview

In Apple iAd programming guide, in the apple developer library with a date of 9/17/14, I'm looking to make that when user clicks on iAd banner and game is in Portrait mode, that the banner shows in portrait mode and not landscape like i'm currently getting. The following is the code I found in the 9/17/14 version of iAd programming guidelines.

```
  ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
  adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
  [self.view addSubview:adView];
```

Problem is Xcode 6.1 tells me  ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait has been deprecated after iOS 6.0. Don't know why a deprecated code was inside a 9/17/14 made guideline. So what is the non-depracated code to make the iPad/iPhone load iAd in Portrait or UpsideDown mode?

Answer (score 1):

First you could try `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;`
Second, you could make an `ADBannerView` and set the size due to the orientation.

```
ADBannerView *banner = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];    
if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width < [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height){
        banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 640);
        [self.view addSubview:banner];
}
```